# PHP: is_dir() for folders such as "./folder" return false unless I specify them as "../folder"

Tags: php, filesystems

The hierarchy of my site is like this:

```
/
/webroot/
/webroot/index.php
/webroot/images/foo.jpg
```

I do not have write permissions for `/`, but I do for anything within `/webroot`.
Now say within index.php I have any of these commands:

```
var_dump(is_dir('./images/frontpage'));
var_dump(is_dir('images/frontpage'));
var_dump(is_dir('/webroot/images/frontpage'));
var_dump(is_dir('.\images\frontpage'));
```

They will all return `false`. But if within `webroot\index.php` I have...

```
    var_dump(is_dir('../images'));
```

...they return `true`. Am I missing something obvious? Is it supposed to work this way? I don't understand this.

BUT: If I have something like this:

```
/
/webroot/
/webroot/index.php
/webroot/images/foo.jpg
/webroot/subfolder/index.php
```

Then `var_dump(is_dir('../images'));` will return `true` both in `index.php` and in `subfolder/index.php`

Comment: Um, is index.php a directory or a file? You're kind of implying both.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed with additional info.

Comment: Try using getcwd (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and you should see what the default directory is.

Answer (score 1):

Both will return true if you are calling them from `/webroot/subfolder/`.

`..` and `.` depends on your *current working directory*. Calling `/webroot/index.php` from `/webroot/subfolder/some.php` will make `/webroot/subfolder/` the *current working directory*. Hence `'../images'` will always be a directory and it'll return true.

Comment: That's just the thing. If I run `is_dir('../images')` from `/webroot/subfolder/index.php`, I would expect it to return true, and it does. But when I run `is_dir('../images')` from `/webroot/index.php`, I would think that would be looking for `/images`, but it still returns true. As if the current working directory is always some subfolder of `/webroot/` even when working directly inside `/webroot`. It is quite possible that what you are saying is correct, and I'm just not understanding it...